# How to wrap <a> tags with <H1> tag?

Tags: html, tags

I have the following:

```
<a class="clickable_element" href="https://www.mywebsite.com"> ==$0
   <div class="content">My Website</div>
</a>
```

I want to wrap all this in a "h1" tag.

How would I go about doing this using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You would first have to create the h1 tag, append it to the DOM. Then append the  tag to the  tag.
Like this

```
const aTag = document.querySelector('a')
const h1Tag = document.createElement('h1')

document.body.appendChild(h1Tag)
h1Tag.appendChild('aTag')
```

Comment: As the user is likely to be new to, or inexperienced with, JavaScript (and for other users visiting the question in the future), your answer may benefit from some explanation as to what the code does, or how it works. I agree it's simple code, and it's relatively easy to search for documentation, but ideally an answer would be self-contained, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to wrap this with `h1` if you can just create a class for the `div`, but here's the code you can try:

HTML

```
<h1 id="wrap">
</h1>
```

JS

`document.getElementById("wrap").innerHTML = "<a href='test.html'><div>My Website</div></a>"`